# Maaser on Sal Klita

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, aliya-laaretz

As a new immigrant to Israel I am receiving a little bit of money ( http://www.jewishagency.org/NR/exeres/A2A4F6FE-5CB4-469E-A45C-517CF14D59D5 ) to get started here.

Should I pay maaser on this money? Which income is eligible for maaser?

Comment: Congratulations on your move! We wish you much success in your ventures there.

Comment: some related material http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/166/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8846/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12863/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/maaser-deductibles

Comment: Your question might be much more comprehensible and answerable if you'd explain more about this money transfer.

Comment: @msh210 Sal Klita: http://www.jewishagency.org/NR/exeres/A2A4F6FE-5CB4-469E-A45C-517CF14D59D5

Comment: If you'd like the question could be generalized to maaser on "Financial Aid". Should I edit?

Comment: @nute, I'd recommend that you leave it about Sal Klita in particular just in case there are particular aspects of that that are Halachically relevant and interesting, and [edit] in as much detail as you can about the nature of this income, especially anything that you think might be Halachically relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your first question is yes. The short answer to your second question is any income from any source.

As explained in [When does the obligation of Maaser money begin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67353/when-does-the-obligation-of-maaser-money-begin/67354#67354) ma'aser applies to any income (including an income tax refund). For example, a person getting **money** from tzedakah is still chayav to pay maaser on that income. That is because it is considered a neder (as Yaakov made to Hashem). Thus, any money that comes in from any source (including gifts, tzedakah, unemployment insurance payments,  or the klitah) would be subject to maaser. Note that I am not comparing klitah to tzedakah but giving examples that people might think are not subject to ma'aser.

Thanks to @mbloch for this pointer [Does Ma'aser need to be given on gifts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/166/does-maaser-need-to-be-given-on-gifts/66612#66612) giving a more nuanced explanation of gifts

See [this list](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=maaser+kesafim&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=77597213965&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=s&hvrand=4685784851622008621&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_8wssbgovvm_b)

Comment: +1 but I think it is more nuanced re gifts, see what I wrote [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66612/11501)